# How to drive 12V servo motors using 5V PWM or 3.3V PWM using ARM MCU?

Tags: electrical-engineering, microelectronics, pwm

I have to drive several 12V servo motors. So I wanna to get 12V PWM Controller (12V Logic Controller). I have MCU as Atmel SAM3X8E arduino due board. It has 5V PWM outs. Is there any Controller IC available for this task?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Motor Driver board: limited current](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/549/motor-driver-board-limited-current?rq=1) for additional ideas.

Comment: Edit your question with a datasheet.  The term *servo motor* means entirely different things in the hobbyist market than it does in the industrial market; advise applicable to one type may let the smoke out of the other.

Comment: Would need more information on the servo but I would use a MOSFET.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ARDUINO MOTOR SHIELD REV3](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-motor-shield-rev3). Here is what it looks like. If you have several motors then might have to stack several motor shields.

[image]